# Law of Large Numbers under Transformation

Tags: law-of-large-numbers

The Law of Large Number, draw i.i.d examples of a random variable y, then with propability of 1 the average of y_1, ... y_n goes to the expected value of y.

When i apply a function to the y_i's, does then also hold that the average of f(y_1), ... f(y_n) goes to the expected value of f(y).

Does the function f needs to fullfil certain conditions for this to hold?

Comment: Would writing "$f(y_i)$" as "$x_i$" help?

Comment: @whuber It seems that $f(y_i)$ is just a sample of the random variablen $f(y)$. So it should still work however the mean and variance of the random variable changes, is this correct?

Comment: I find that very confusing: if the mean and variance of a "random variable" can change, then it's not a random variable anymore.  Are you trying to model a *stochastic process*?  In my comment I was trying to suggest that you simplify your notation and then forget how the $x_i$ were computed and focus on the fact that you have them.  Is there any aspect of your situation that would prevent application of laws of large numbers to them?

Comment: @whuber no all i wanted to say is that the mean of y is different to f(y). No i don't think so